# Do I need AtomicInteger inside a synchronized(anyObject) block?

Tags: java, multithreading

I want to keep track of a position inside a queue that gets modified inside a `synchronized` block. Therefore I need a counter variable. Normally I would use `AtomicInteger` but do I need that here?

```
PriorityBlockingQueue<TfIdfScore> allScores = sharedFeatureNameToScores.get(featureName);

synchronized (allScores) {

    AtomicInteger position = positionCounterMap.get(featureName);               
    position.getAndAdd(1);

    // Do other stuff..
}
```

Or could I use `int` or `Integer` as well? Does the `synchronized` block protect all my actions inside the block?

In this example `position` and `allScores` depend on the same `featureName`.

Comment: A `synchronized(foo)` block does not protect against _anything_ except other threads synchronizing on the same object `foo` at the same time.  You can _use_ that feature to protect your data by making sure that none of your threads ever accesses the data except from inside a `synchronized(foo)` block.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are writing all of the code (and taking appropriate care) then you don't need to to use both `synchronized` and an atomic type.  Just make sure that all operations on a given map and the counters it contains synchronize on the same object while they do that ... and that part of the code should thread-safe.

On the other hand, if you are worried that someone will forget to synchronize, then an atomic type probably won't solve the problem.  A better solution is to make sure that the map and the counters well encapsulated, to reduce the scope for mistakes.  (If you can reduce the amount of code can access the state, that reduces the number of places you need to check for thread safety.)

---

> Does the synchronized block protect all my actions inside the block?

Not necessarily.

You can still have thread-safety problems if there is *other* code accessing or updating the data structures, and *that* code is not synchronizing on the right mutex; e.g. the same `allScores` instance.

Comment: Thank you! I think encapulation might be a good idea - I'll have to check if it is  necessary but it is a good thing to keep in mind for the future!

Answer (score 1):

Synchronized is a more strict then atomic or volatile. Thus you have no need to use atomic in synchronized

Synchronized

> Synchronized methods enable a simple strategy for preventing thread interference and memory consistency errors: if an object is visible to more than one thread, all reads or writes to that object's variables are done through synchronized methods.

Volatile

> volatile field means that variable won't be cached in processors core/threads. Thus you will have only one copy of variable per all cores/threads

atomic

> The java.util.concurrent.atomic package defines classes that support atomic operations on single variables. All classes have get and set methods that work like reads and writes on volatile variables. That is, a set has a happens-before relationship with any subsequent get on the same variable. The atomic compareAndSet method also has these memory consistency features, as do the simple atomic arithmetic methods that apply to integer atomic variables.

Answer (score 1):

In your code you are using two different object using featureName: `sharedFeatureNameToScores` and `positionCounterMap`.

In order to guarantee that your code is thread safe you need to ensure that the modifications to both of them is made using the same lock (`synchronized (allScores)` in you code). Once you satisfy this requirement there is no need to user AtomicInteger since the synchronized block protects both so the access to `positionCounterMap` is made in exclusive mode.